# Why does GitHub Desktop lose formatting in some files?

Tags: windows, windows-8, github

For some files, even though the formatting is preserved in the IDE (I use Sublime Text Editor btw), when I make a change and then open up Github Desktop to check for changes, the formatting is all lost.

[image]

I'm yet to figure out why does it happen with a particular file and not all files. Any inputs?

Comment: Can you define how these files are deformed, for example are end-of-lines deleted or replaced, is white space deleted, etc.

Comment: Have you configured Git  to correctly handle line endings on Windows by `git config --global core.autocrlf true`? More info [here](https://help.github.com/articles/dealing-with-line-endings/).

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you've edited the file on Windows which uses a different encoding for the new lines. Git for Windows includes an option to convert the newline characters when you commit. GitHub has documented it here: https://help.github.com/articles/dealing-with-line-endings/

Comment: I edit all my files on Windows. What's puzzling is if that is the case, then why do 90% of the files have their formatting preserved but the rest have it all garbled up.